# SQLite in Visual Studio 2013 .net 4.0 -- Getting Started Help & Questions

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2013, system.data.sqlite

I need some general, newbie, getting-started help trying to use SQLite in Visual Studio 2013 on the .net 4.0 framework in a desktop application.

We have this desktop app in which all clients can connect to a central database, but can also work offline (disconnected) as well, when laptops are out in the field.  We've been using XML for the local datastore, which works okay when the dataset is limited.  However, we have recently landed some new, larger clients, and sometimes their local data can be in excess of 200,000 rows of data.  At this point, the XML solution is not so great.  It's way, way too slow.

So, I wanted to try out SQLite as a proof of concept and see if it works any better.  We have a copy of the client's database on our dev server, so we can test with their (large amounts of) data.

I've used SQLite in mobile development before, but never in Visual Studio.  I expected the implementation of it to be simple and straight forward.  This has not been the case. I've found several smaller third part .dll's, some of which seems to be defunct.  Mostly I've been focusing on System.Data.SQLite.  But even this is proving to be a challenge.

This is their download page: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

And the (simple?) task of figuring out which package to download is making my head spin.  I started with:

```
    sqlite-netFx40-setup-x64-2010-1.0.94.0.exe
```

I thought I had it installed and working properly, only to find out that it does not have any design-time support. So I uninstalled it and tried:

```
    sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x64-2010-1.0.94.0.exe.
```

But when I tried to execute it in debug mode, I kept getting this error:

```
  Unable to load DLL SQLite.Interop.dll The specified module could not be found. Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E
```

I spent some time on Google and found this to be a very common error with lots of people offering suggestions on how they fixed it, none of which worked for me. I also noticed that the install process did not even come CLOSE to creating the kind of folder structure that I was told to expect:

```
 <bin>\App.exe (optional, managed-only application executable assembly)
 <bin>\App.dll (optional, managed-only application library assembly)
 <bin>\System.Data.SQLite.dll (required, managed-only core assembly)
 <bin>\System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll (optional, managed-only LINQ assembly)
 <bin>\System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll (optional, managed-only EF6 assembly)
 <bin>\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll (required, x86 native interop assembly)
 <bin>\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll (required, x64 native interop assembly)
```

In frustration I uninstalled everything and rolled back my solution to where it had been before I tried all of this.  I'm now back to ground-zero.  And I need some guidance.  Some questions:

Have you used SQLite in Visual Studio?

If so, what 3rd party tool do you use?

If System.Data.SQLite is the best option, then how on God's Green Earth do I pick the correct download option?

And once I have downloaded the correct .exe, is there a correct way to install it (from within VS?) so that it creates the expected folder structure inside the bin directory?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There is an official SQLite SDK which I think you can add through NuGet.

Comment: I should also ask this question:  Is SQLite the best option for what we're trying to do:  Manage several hundred rows of locally stored data on client's machine?

Comment: Thanks Jeroen.  I'll Google that,  but in the mean time, might you have a link?

Comment: If you go to *Tools* -> *Extensions and Updates* -> *Online* You'll find there are SQLite downloads available for WP8, WP8.1, WinRT and Win8.1.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen those.  There are a lot, actually.  I'm hoping that someone can say, "I've used THIS one, and I recommend it."

Comment: Ok, I think the "official" NuGet option just points back to System.Data.SQLite.

Comment: Use whichever you need.. They are specifically targetted at different platforms so take the platform you're using.

Comment: Part of the problem here is that our clients run this app on everything from WinXP to Win 8. So I'm hesitant to use a solution that specifies an OS.  And I don't need anything for Windows Phone.